# Why does the Rust documentation say that sharing a reference to a vector would create an invalid vector even though the vector is on the heap?

Tags: rust, memory-safety

The following is an excerpt from *The Rust Programming Language* [chapter on ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ownership.html):

> Now consider the following code fragment:
>
> ```
> let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
>
> let mut v2 = v;
> ```
>
> The first line allocates memory for the vector object `v` on the stack
>   like it does for `x` above. But in addition to that it also allocates
>   some memory on the heap for the actual data (`[1, 2, 3]`). Rust copies
>   the address of this heap allocation to an internal pointer, which is
>   part of the vector object placed on the stack (let's call it the data
>   pointer).
>
> It is worth pointing out (even at the risk of stating the obvious)
>   that the vector object and its data live in separate memory regions
>   instead of being a single contiguous memory allocation (due to reasons
>   we will not go into at this point of time). These two parts of the
>   vector (the one on the stack and one on the heap) must agree with each
>   other at all times with regards to things like the length, capacity,
>   etc.
>
> When we move `v` to `v2`, Rust actually does a bitwise copy of the vector
>   object `v` into the stack allocation represented by `v2`. This shallow
>   copy does not create a copy of the heap allocation containing the
>   actual data. Which means that there would be two pointers to the
>   contents of the vector both pointing to the same memory allocation on
>   the heap. It would violate Rust’s safety guarantees by introducing a
>   data race if one could access both `v` and `v2` at the same time.
>
> For example if we truncated the vector to just two elements through
>   `v2`:
>
> ```
> v2.truncate(2);
> ```
>
> and `v` were still accessible we'd end up with an invalid vector since `v`
>   would not know that the heap data has been truncated. Now, the part of
>   the vector `v` on the stack does not agree with the corresponding part
>   on the heap. `v` still thinks there are three elements in the vector and
>   will happily let us access the non existent element `v[2]` but as you
>   might already know this is a recipe for disaster. Especially because
>   it might lead to a segmentation fault or worse allow an unauthorized
>   user to read from memory to which they don't have access.

After truncating the vector using `v2`, the truncated values are updated on the heap memory. `v1` still sees the heap memory and after truncation, it sees the new values. So why does the book say

> and `v` were still accessible we'd end up with an invalid vector since `v` would not know that the heap data has been truncated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that a `Vec` contains both a pointer to the heap and a `len`, or length of the heap's data.  If `v2` truncates the `Vec`, it's possible that the truncated data has been freed, and `v1` still believes that the truncated memory is still part of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I understand it. The key is to know that Rust has this internal pointer which is again a space on the stack that Rust uses to locate the address of the data on the heap!

If `v2` changes this data on the heap, `v2`'s internal pointer gets updated with the new data allocation address, while `v1`'s internal pointer would still refer to the old data allocation address!